# Load image if required in list view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-inflate

I have a row layout with

1. image
2. title which gets inflated on a list view.

The problem is the image should be of size 80dp x 80dp where there is no guarantee as the image may be null in the DB. So I would like to know how we could check wether for the availability of the image in the db.If it is available then inflate the image aligned left with the size 80dp x 80dp in the row layout that is inflated for a list view. Elhe nse don't display the image. (Using Picasso to load images over the network)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In picasso there is a method called error.Then if the url is wrong then the image in the error is loaded.You should only check if the image path is null by checking the string.

Comment: The problem is not with checking if the image part is null or not as it is pretty straight forward ... but it actually is inflating the image view only if the image exists or displaying an image view of size 80dp x 80dp if it exists  else it should not show any image only the text would be visible

Comment: but it actually is inflating the image view only if the image exists...can u explain this?

Comment: My use case is I want to display an image view of size 80dp x 80dp inside a custom list view if the image is not there the 80dp x 80dp space would be empty but I want my text view to fill that place too and this space shouldnt get wasted if image is not present

Comment: then you can do it by using android:visibility="gone" for the imageview when there is no image present

Comment: how do I do that ??? Is it done programatically or using it in the row_layout.xml used to inflate the custom list view

Comment: It is done programatically.use this imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);